# Karma unit testing: Module name "react" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, requirejs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to set up the unit testing framework for react. While doing so, the following error has occurred. I have searched all over the internet with no solution that is working. below are the errors shown and code/packages that I am using.

debug error

```
04 03 2016 04:48:46.340:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]: Error: Module name "react" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded


04 03 2016 04:48:46.341:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]:   http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/requirejs/require.js?6f53c895855c3743ac6fb7f99afc63ca5cdfd300:140 in defaultOnError
  http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/requirejs/require.js?6f53c895855c3743ac6fb7f99afc63ca5cdfd300:544 in onError
  http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/requirejs/require.js?6f53c895855c3743ac6fb7f99afc63ca5cdfd300:1429 in localRequire
  http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/requirejs/require.js?6f53c895855c3743ac6fb7f99afc63ca5cdfd300:1791 in requirejs

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Module name "react" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
  at /Users/lebeier/Documents/iMARS/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:140
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.053 secs / 0 secs)
```

node packages

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "highcharts": "^4.2.1",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^1.4.5",
    "react-data-components": "^0.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-highcharts": "^6.0.0",
    "react-notification-system": "^0.2.6",
    "react-router": "^1.0.3",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "toastr": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.6.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.1.3",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs": "^0.2.3",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.21",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
    "karma-browserify": "^5.0.2",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.5",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.22",
    "uglify": "^0.1.5",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14"
  }
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

  // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
  basePath: '',

  // frameworks to use
  // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
  frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
  files: [
      'tests/*.js'
      //{ pattern: 'tests.webpack.js', watched: false }, 
  ],

  // list of files to exclude
  //exclude: [
  //  './node_modules/'
  //],

  plugins: [
    'karma-jasmine',
    'karma-requirejs',
    'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
    'karma-babel-preprocessor',
    'karma-coverage',
    'karma-browserify',
    'karma-webpack'
  ],

  // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
  // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
  preprocessors: {
    'core/static/core/js/*.js' : ['babel'],
    'tests/*.js' : ['babel'],
    'tests.webpack.js': [ 'webpack']
  },

  babelPreprocessor:{
    options: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
        plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
        sourceMap: 'inline'
    },
    filename: function(file){
        return file.originalPath.replace(/\.js$/, '.es5.js');
    },
    sourceFileName: function(file){
        return file.originalPath;
    }
  },
  // test results reporter to use
  // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
  // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
  reporters: ['dots'],


  // web server port
  port: 9876,


  // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
  colors: true,


  // level of logging
  // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
  logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


  // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
  autoWatch: true,

  // start these browsers
  // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
  browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

  // Continuous Integration mode
  // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
  singleRun: true,

  // Concurrency level
  // how many browser should be started simultaneous
  concurrency: Infinity,

  webpack: {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    modules: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query:{
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ],
      },
      watch: true,
    },

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true,
    }
  })
}
```

tests/test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

describe('Testing', ()=>{
    it('sample test', ()=>{
        var v = 2;
        var parts = ['shoulders', 'knees'];
        var lyrics = ['head', ...parts, 'and', 'toes'];
        expect(v).toEqual(2); 
    }); 
});
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you describe is exactly what RequireJS gives you when you have a `require` call in the CommonJS form (`require('modX')`) instead of the AMD form (`require(['modX'], function (modX) {...})`), **and** the call is done without being wrapped in `define`. RequireJS provides some support for using the CommonJS form, but there is a minimum of work that must be done by the developer to ensure that it works. A script that starts with this won't work:

```
var modX = require('modX');
// rest of the module
```

You get the error message you got. You need this instead:

```
define(function (require) {
    var modX = require('modX');
    // rest of the module
});
```

What is going on with your setup is that, as it is, Babel is transforming the ES6 modules into something that uses `require` without the `define` wrapper. In order to get Babel to output proper AMD modules, you need to install `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd` and add `transform-es2015-modules-amd` to your list of Babel plugins. See the documentation [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-amd/).

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response, I will give it a try and get back to you if it works =)

Comment: While this does solve the error, but it still fails to run the test =(... nonetheless, I will mark this as answer since it answers my questions =)

Comment: You did the right thing. There was a clear problem in your question. You got an answer that solved the problem. Case closed. Sometimes, users will edit their question to add a new problem that they run into once the one that was in their original question is solved. This is really not appreciated by the community. Taken in the extreme (multiple edits), they turn into what the community calls [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478).  If you run into a new issue, you can write a new question. Make sure it is not a duplicate before posting.